# Initialization loop Golang

Tags: unit-testing, go, mocking, testify

Hi I'm trying to make my function unit testable. One of the suggestion was to assign the function into a variable and make it globally accessible. I just did that but now I'm experiencing a Initialization loop below is my code

```
////////////////////////
// main.go
////////////////////////

func DownloadFile(filename string) {
    // Initialized request variable here
    // ... doing initialization
    // End of initialization

    res = ProcessDownload(request)

    if res == 401 {
       return doRetry(filename)
    }

    // some code here
    return downloadFile(filename)
}

func DoRetry(filename string) {
    // Doing some database insert/updating
   return downloadFile(string)
}
```

And in my other file I assign this function into variable

```
//////////////////////
// global.go
//////////////////////

var downloadFile = DownloadFile
var doRetry = DoRetry
```

The reason I did this in the global.go was to make the **DoRetry** and **DownloadFile** unit testable. Meaning with this method I can **MOCK** the function without creating an interface. Since this is just a standalone function and don't need to be within a certain class. All the rest of the variable is ok but when it comes to a function doing a recursive behavior I get the error below

```
./global.go:22:5: initialization loop:
/go/src/project/global.go:22:5 downloadFile refers to
/go/src/project/process.go:403:99 DownloadFile refers to
/go/src/project/global.go:23:5 doRetry refers to
/go/src/project/process.go:394:89 DoRetry refers to
/go/src/project/global.go:22:5 downloadFile
FAIL    project [build failed]
```

I know this maybe a duplicate in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31726254/how-to-avoid-initialization-loop-in-go) but I can't see how the solution in here solve my problem.

Please help me on this. Thanks
I read about mocking a function in this link

[Mock functions in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167970/mock-functions-in-go)

https://husobee.github.io/golang/testing/unit-test/2015/06/08/golang-unit-testing.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is to not assign values when you declare your `downloadFile` and `doRetry` function variables, but "defer" the initialization to a package `init()` function, like this:

```
var downloadFile func(string) //= DownloadFile
var doRetry func(string)      //= DoRetry

func init() {
    downloadFile = DownloadFile
    doRetry = DoRetry
}
```

This way the variables first will be initialized with `nil` (zero value for function types) which means they don't depend on the `DownloadFile()` and `DoRetry()` functions, and *later* when the package `init()` function runs, that will assign the function values to the variables, so no initialization loop will occur.

Comment: Wow this sounds perfect. Just one noob question. Where should I place the function init()? Can this go into any file? or should it be under main.go?

Comment: @MadzmarUllang Intuitively you should place this `init()` function right under the variables they initialize, if it doesn't cause any troubles. You can have multiple package `init()` functions.

Comment: Great will try this. I think this will really solve it

Comment: Tried it and it works... Thank you so much you really saved me here